# What is the proper self-aid during a heart attack?

Tags: heart-disease, first-aid, heart-attack, self-help

I've heard that using cough during heart attacks as an improvised CPR [is a complete myth](https://www.heart.org/en/health-topics/cardiac-arrest/emergency-treatment-of-cardiac-arrest/cough-cpr). (**Important note disproving self-CPR**: CPR shall not be performed on conscious people.)

My question is what are the proper actions and tactics for self-aid during a heart attack? Is any form of self-<del>CPR</del> **aid** a thing? How effective is it?

Comment: If by "heart attack" you mean cardiac arrest, self-CPR is impossible because you will be unconscious and there's absolutely nothing you can do for yourself. And if you're not in cardiac arrest, there would be no reason to perform CPR. So it's a nonsensical myth and the only course of action you should take if you believe you're having a heart attack is calling the emergency services number in your country.

Comment: @CareyGregory you are totally right, sorry. Self-CPR was **rich** on my behalf as it shall not be performed on conscious people. The proper wording is the one I used in the head title - "**self-aid** during heart attacks". I will edit the post.

Comment: 1) Call for help 2) Take a seat or lie down, to avoid falling if you become unconscious. Note that calling for help both mean call the emergency services by phone, and call for friends or passers-by so they can call the emergency services for you, as well as deliver CPR if you go into cardiac arrest.